# classifying new member into existing cluster in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, classification, cluster-analysis, text-classification

There is a group of texts `GROUP` from `text[:n]` (say 1-100 as an example) and a matrix of their cosine similarity to each other:

```
     001   002   003  ...   100
001    1  0.53  0.47  ...  0.79
002 0.53     1  0.55  ...  0.30
003 0.47  0.55     1  ...  0.21
...  ...   ...   ...    1   ...
100 0.79  0.30  0.21  ...     1
```

When a new member `text[n+1]` is created, I would like to know whether `text[n+1]` is **something new** to the group. That is, it does not belong to any of the potential clusters in `text[1-100]` based on their surface similarity.

Knowing just a little about the variety of clustering techniques, I would like to know how to best complete this classification in Python. There are two rather general ways I am now doing some research about:

Whenever a new member `text[n+1]` is added to the existing `GROUP`:`text[:n]`:

1. Run a clustering algorithm to cluster `text[:n]` based on their cosine similarity, then calculate the probability that `text[n+1]` belong to one of the existing clusters and the probability that it should be in a new cluster on its own. -> then use the probability to decide whether `text[n+1]` is "something new" or "something that similar stuff is already in our data before"
2. Alternatively, if I don't care about how many clusters are in `text[:n]`, but simply whether `text[n+1` is something new, is it possible to simplify the process to classifying `text[n+1]` to a binary `0 (something seen before)` or `1 (something new)` with better computational efficiency?

Also, would something like *Chinese restaurant process* be potentially relevant to the question here? I appreciate any suggestions and resources you can point me towards as well.

Comment: I believe you can use DBSCAN in an online way with relatively little changes. This allows you to assign the new point to an existing cluster _or_ create a new cluster https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is not classification.

Do *not* rely on the results being good, or stable - running it twice may yield very different results, and some clusters may good, others may be bad. So study them, then label your data and use classification rather than clustering.

That later hack is easy to do (train a classifier, based on your clusters) but I am not convinced it is useful in reality.